# Intersection of two large word lists

Tags: dictionary, grep, intersection

I have two word lists (180k and 260k), and I would like to generate a third file which is the set of words that appear in BOTH lists.

What is the best (most efficient) way of doing this? I've read forums talking about using *grep*, however I think the word lists are too big for this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two files are sorted (or you can sort them), you can use `comm -1 -2 file1 file2` to print out the intersection.

Comment: It turns out one of them is sorted -- could you give me a command to sort the other one?

Comment: Just `sort -o outfile infile`, assuming the other file is sorted alphabetically as well.  Be careful about locales, though; in particular, whether the order is "AaBb" or "ABab" can change.  To be safe, you might want to sort both files explicitly so you're sure you are using the same settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeremiah! The sort worked fine, but the *comm* still warned 'comm: file 2 is not in sorted order' -- But it seemed to have generated *something*. Does this sound OK? I'll do some QA in the morning :)

Comment: That warning probably means the files were not sorted in the exact same order; try explicitly sorting both of them and try the `comm` command again.

Comment: Oh yes, that seemed to have worked. Also, Johnsyweb's grep method produced the same result, so I'm pretty confident about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, grep would be a bad idea. Type "*man join*" and follow the instructions.

If your files are just lists of words in a single column, or at least, if the important word is the first on each line, then all you need to do is:

```
$ sort -b -o f1 file1
$ sort -b -o f2 file2
$ join f1 f2
```

Otherwise, you may need to give the join(1) command some additional instructions:

```
JOIN(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  JOIN(1)

NAME
     join -- relational database operator

SYNOPSIS
     join [-a file_number | -v file_number] [-e string] [-o list] [-t char] [-1 field] [-2 field] file1 file2

DESCRIPTION
     The join utility performs an ``equality join'' on the specified files and writes the result to the standard output.  The ``join field'' is the field in each file by which the files are compared.  The
     first field in each line is used by default.  There is one line in the output for each pair of lines in file1 and file2 which have identical join fields.  Each output line consists of the join field,
     the remaining fields from file1 and then the remaining fields from file2.
     . . .
     . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming one word per line, I would use `grep`:

```
grep -xFf seta setb
```

- `-x` matches the whole lines (no partial matches)
- `-F` interprets the given patterns literally (no regular expressions)
- `-f seta` specifies the patterns to search
- `setb` is the file to search for the contents of `seta`

`comm` will do the same thing, but requires your sets to be pre-sorted:

```
comm -12 <(sort seta) <(sort setb)
```

Comment: the *grep -xFf* also worked, and seems to produce the same result (judging by the equal number of lines in the result). I think it took a bit longer (computationally) than the *comm* method (as one would expect, of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`grep -P '[ A-Za-z0-9]*' file1 | xargs -0 -I {} grep {} file2 > file3`

I believe this looks for anything in file1, then checks if what was in file1 is in file2, and puts anything that matches into file3.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days I managed to find a Perl script that does something similar:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=160735

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.